# The following packages are not available: - Package id system-images;android-19;armeabi-v7a

Tags: android

I have an older computer and I installed Android IDE and tried to run my first app. I get the error "The following packages are not available: - Package id system-images;android-19;armeabi-v7a". My CPU does not support VT-x so it says the only option is "Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image". Please help.